# readFileSync error occurs when to read yaml file

Tags: typescript, yaml

I'm trying to read a yaml file with Type Script. But I get an error of readFileSync and cannot read it. What should I do?

> fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync is not a function

```
import fs from 'fs'
import yaml from 'js-yaml'

export const en = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('./en.yml', 'utf8'))
```

Comment: Using webpack suggests your code runs in a browser and not in Nodejs. The fs library is a nodejs library though, so you cannot use it on the client side.

Comment: So how can I solve that?

Comment: You can't. For security reasons, it is not possible to read files from client side directly. You will have to use the browser API for that - and let the user select the file for upload. Or you have to serve the file on your server and download it via http request (e.g. By using fetch Api)